# How to trigger a marketing goal in Sitecore and later see it in reports?

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-analytics, sitecore-xdb

I am triggering marketing goals using back-end code as follows:

```
if (!TrackerEnabled())
{
    Tracker.StartTracking();
}

Item goal = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalId);


var goalAsPageEvent = new PageEventItem(goal);
var pageEventsRow = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.CurrentPage.Register(goalAsPageEvent);
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Submit();
```

And I can see the data in MongoDB interactions table as follows:

```
"PageEvents" : [ 
{
    "Name" : "Apply Now - Auto Loans",
    "Timestamp" : NumberLong(0),
    "PageEventDefinitionId" : LUUID("dc9d7115-7bd5-7b40-9fa5-2722a2fb2e00"),
    "IsGoal" : true,
    "DateTime" : ISODate("2016-07-28T12:47:33.700Z"),
    "Value" : 25
},
// ...
]
```

My question is: how can I see this data in Sitecore Experience Analytics or Content Editor?

Comment: Using `Tracker.StartTracking()` and `Tracker.Submit()` is a bad practice. Why would you do this? You should track goals in the context of a page, where tracker is already active. And `Tracker.Submit()` will be called for you by Sitecore, you shouldn't do that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will be able to see this in Experience Analytics in aggregated state.

If you want to see this data in Sitecore with details you should use [Experience Profile application](https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2014/11/01/sitecore-8-overview-of-experience-profile/).